# php undefinex index

Tags: php, java, html, índices

index.html
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Cadastro de Clientes

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

</head>

<nav class="navbar-default navbar navbar col-lg-12">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1" align="center">
   <td><img src="logo1.png"  class="img-responsive text-center"/>
     <h4 class="text-center">CADASTRO DE CLIENTES</h4>
    <font color = "black"><b></b></font></td>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="col-lg-14">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
color: #FF0000;
font-size: x-small;
}
.style3 {color: #0000FF; font-size: x-small; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaCampo()
{
if(document.cadastro.nome.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo nome e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.email.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo email e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.endereco.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo endereco e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.cpf.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo endereco e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.cep.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo endereco e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.cidade.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Cidade e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.estado.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Estado e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.bairro.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Bairro e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.pais.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.representante.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.marca.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.banco.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.agencia.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.cc.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.titularCC.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país e obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
return true;
}
<!-- Fim do JavaScript que validará os campos obrigatórios! -->
</script>

<body>
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="cadastro.php" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
 <table width="625" border="0">

     <tr>
      <td width="69">Nome:</td>
      <td width="546"><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="70" maxlength="60" /><p>
          </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CPF/CNPJ:</td>
      <td><input name="cpf" type="text" id="cpf" maxlength="20" /><p>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Endereco:</td>
      <td><input name="endereco" type="text" id="endereco" size="50" maxlength="50" />
      Numero:
     <input name="numero" type="text" id="numero" size="5"/><p>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CEP</td>
      <td><input name="cep" type="text" id="ddd" size="10" maxlength="20" />
        Cidade:
        <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" />
        Estado:
      <select name="estado" id="estado">
        <option>...</option>
        <option value="AC">AC</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="AP">AP</option>
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="BA">BA</option>
        <option value="CE">CE</option>
        <option value="ES">ES</option>
        <option value="DF">DF</option>
        <option value="MA">MA</option>
        <option value="MT">MT</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
        <option value="MG">MG</option>
        <option value="PA">PA</option>
        <option value="PB">PB</option>
        <option value="PR">PR</option>
        <option value="PE">PE</option>
        <option value="PI">PI</option>
        <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
        <option value="RN">RN</option>
        <option value="RS">RS</option>
        <option value="RO">RO</option>
        <option value="RR">RR</option>
        <option value="SC">SC</option>
        <option value="SP">SP</option>
        <option value="SE">SE</option>
        <option value="TO">TO</option>
          </select><p>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Bairro:</td>
      <td><input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" maxlength="20" />
    País:
      <input name="pais" type="text" id="pais" maxlength="20" /><p>

    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>DDD:</td>
      <td><input name="ddd" type="text" id="ddd" size="4" maxlength="2" />
      Telefone:
        <input  name="tel" type="text" id="tel" />
        <span class="style3">Apenas números</span><p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="70" maxlength="60" /><p>

    </tr>

 <tr>

<tr>
      <td>Escritorio de Representação: </td>
      <td><input name="rep" type="text" size="70" id="rep"/><p>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Marca:</td>
  <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="marca[]" id="coca" value="Coca Cola">Coca Cola </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="marca[]" id="diversao" value="Diversao/Hasbro">Diversao/Hasbro </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="marca[]" id="reserva" value="Reserva">Reserva </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="marca[]" id="puket" value="Puket">Puket </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="marca[]" id="capricho" value="Capricho">Capricho </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="marca[]" id="times" value="Times">Times </label><p></td>
     <p>   
</tr>

<tr>
      <td>Rede de Loja: </td>
      <td><input name="rede" type="text" size="70" id="rede"/><p>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banco:</td>
            <td><select name="banco" id="banco">
             <option>Selecione...</option>
              <option>Banco ABC</option>
             <option>Banco do Brasil</option>
<option>Banco do Nordeste</option>
<option>Banco Safra</option>
<option>Banco Votorantim</option>
<option> Banco Sicredi</option>
<option>Banrisul</option>
<option>BNDES</option>
<option>Bradesco</option>
<option>BTG Pactual</option>
<option>Caixa Economica Federal</option>
<option>Citibank Brasil</option>
<option>HSBC Brasil</option>
<option>Itaú Unibanco</option>
<option>Santander Brasil</option>
<option>Sicoob </option>
</select>
      Agencia:
        <input name="agencia" type="text" size="4" id="agencia"/>
      Conta Corrente:
      <input name="cc" type="text" size="5" id="cc"/><p>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nome Titular: </td>
      <td><input name="titularCC" type="text" size="70" id="titularCC" placeholder="Titular deve ser o mesmo do CPF/CNPJ cadastrado"/><p>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Fotos:<br />
<td><input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
</tr>

 <td colspan="2">
  <br>

 <input class="btn btn-success" name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Concluir meu Cadastro" /> 
 <input name="limpar" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="limpar" value="Limpar Campos preenchidos" />

</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<footer class="text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

cadastro.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Cadastro realizado com sucesso!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//"$conexao" recebe a Conexão com o Banco de Dados
$conexao = pg_connect("host=192.168.1.10 port=5432 dbname=senda user=neviton password=killpain");

//"$sql" string para Inserção de Registros na Tabela
$nome = pg_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
$cpf = pg_escape_string($_POST['cpf']);
$endereco = pg_escape_string($_POST['endereco']);
$numero = pg_escape_string($_POST['numero']);
$cep = pg_escape_string($_POST['cep']);
$cidade = pg_escape_string($_POST['cidade']);
$estado = pg_escape_string($_POST['estado']);
$bairro = pg_escape_string($_POST['bairro']);
$pais = pg_escape_string($_POST['pais']);
$ddd = pg_escape_string($_POST['ddd']);
$telefone = pg_escape_string($_POST['tel']);
$email = pg_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$rep = pg_escape_string($_POST['rep']);
$rede = pg_escape_string($_POST['rede']);
$banco = pg_escape_string($_POST['banco']);
$agencia = pg_escape_string($_POST['agencia']);
$conta = pg_escape_string($_POST['cc']);
$titularCC = pg_escape_string($_POST['titularCC']);
$foto = $_FILES["foto"];

$marca = join(",",$_POST["marca"]);
$arr = array($marca);
$tam = sizeof($arr);

$Vai        = "Nome: $nome\n\n
            cpf: $cpf\n\n
            endereco: $endereco\n\n
            numero: $numero\n\n
            cep: $cep\n\n
            Cidade: $cidade\n\n
            Estado: $estado\n\n
            Bairro: $bairro\n\n
            Pais: $pais\n\n
            Telefone: ($ddd) $telefone\n\n
            Email: $email\n\n
            Rep: $rep\n\n
            Rede: $rede\n\n
            Banco: $banco\n\n
            Agencia: $agencia\n\n
            Conta: $conta\n\n
            TitularCC: $titularCC\n\n
            marca: $marca\n
            ";


for ($i = 0; $i <= $tam-1; $i++) {
}
    if (!empty($foto["name"])) {
        // Largura máxima em pixels
        $largura = 150;
        // Altura máxima em pixels
        $altura = 180;
        // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes
        $tamanho = 1000;

        // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
        if(!eregi("^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$", $foto["type"])){
           $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
        } 
        // Pega as dimensões da imagem
        $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);
        // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida
        if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
            $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
        }
        // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida
        if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
            $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
        }
        // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido
        if($arquivo["size"] > $tamanho) {
            $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
        }

        // Se não houver nenhum erro
        if (count($error) == 0) {

            // Pega extensão da imagem
            preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);

            // Gera um nome único para a imagem
            $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

            // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
            $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;

            // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
            move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);

}
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

define('GUSER', 'relatorio@neorubber.com.br');  // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'neorubber');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    //$mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arquivo['name']); 
    $mail->AddAttachment($foto['tmp_name'], $foto['name']); 
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 
//o nome do email que envia a mensagem, o Assunto da mensagem e por último a variável com o corpo do email.

 if (smtpmailer('neviton2308@gmail.com', 'relatorio@neorubber.com.br', 'neviton', 'email', $Vai)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro.cliente(nome, email, cep, cidade, estado,bairro, cpf, ddd, telefone, endereco, pais, representante, marca, rede, banco, agencia, conta, titularCC, numero) VALUES('". $nome ."','". $email ."','". $cep ."','". $cidade ."','". $estado ."','". $bairro ."','". $cpf ."','". $ddd ."','". $telefone ."','". $endereco ."','". $pais ."','". $rep ."','". $marca ."','". $rede ."','". $banco ."','". $agencia ."','". $conta ."','". $titularCC ."','". $numero ."')";
    ECHO("OBRIGADO");
}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é só um `Notice` do `PHP` ou seja, não impacta na execução do script, porém para que não ocorra, basta ussar um `isset` antes de tentar utilizar a variável:

```
if(isset($_FILES["foto"]))
    $foto = $_FILES["foto"];
```

se eu estiver correto, este é o ponto que está gerando o `Notice`.